# How can I fix this css?

Tags: css, html, web

I am trying to create a website but these images I have are not working, they should be under the title, for example, the alcohol photo should be under the alcohol title and nervous system photo should be under the nervous system title.

Here is a screenshot of how it looks like at the moment:
[image]

Here is my code at the moment:

HTML: http://hastebin.com/utafabumof.xml
CSS: http://hastebin.com/arefipaguy.css

Thank you for helping if you can. it'd mean a lot.

Comment: Remove this rule `.nerimage { padding-left: 1000px; }` and add float to the images. Make the texts the same width as the matching image and add `text-align: center;` to them.

Comment: I have done the edits you told me to do and this is how its came out: https://imgur.com/vXG3sFu new CSS: http://hastebin.com/ijefobikif.css

Comment: Make the first image `float: left` and the second `float: right`.

Comment: Usually, CSS expert isn't using Float property. Because it is difficult making bootstrap page. And it is uncomfortable. If you will define to float in upfront tag of html file, you are difficult to control from the next tag.

Answer (score 0):

The images should be inside the same div, for example alcohol image should be in

```
<div class="science">
    <div class="alco">Image for Alco goes Here</div>
    <div class="nersys">Image for Nersys goes Here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The science class is for the title "Science:"

Comment: @JacobLane I edited right div name just few moments before your comment, my bad.

Comment: That didn't help it just messed up the nervous title.

Comment: @JacobLane Ok, then you need to take both divs(alco and nervous) and put them inside science. Please make sure that image for nervous is inside nervous div, similar to alco. See edited answer.

Comment: this is the change output: https://imgur.com/WGdlj3e. this is the new HTML: http://hastebin.com/yohimilivi.xml. new CSS: http://hastebin.com/badowibomi.css (with your changes you told me to do).

Comment: please could you edit the code in hastebin and send it to me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Science - Portfolio</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/science.css"/>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="about"><a href="english.html">English</a></li>
        <li class="news"><a href="#">Hosptality & Catering</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="#">Leisure & Tourism</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="#">BTEC Computing</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="#">BTEC Business</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="#">CV</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="science">
    <center><h2>Science:</h2></center>
  </div>

  <div class="center-block">
    <div class="alco">
      <h4>Alcohol:</h4>
       <div class="alcoimage"><a href="file:///N|/Documents/My Documents/Year 11/Computing/Website home version/of mice and men.html"><img src="images/Science/alcohol.jpg" width="400" height="357" alt=""/></a></div>
    </div>
<div class="nersys">
    <h4>Nervous System:</h4>
     <div class="alcoimage"><a href="file:///N|/Documents/My Documents/Year 11/Computing/Website home version/cannabis speech.html"><img src="images/Science/NervousSystem.jpg" width="291" height="291" class="nerimage" /></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>



<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="footer">
      <p><center>Contact Me:</center></p>
      <p><center>11lanjac@abbeyfield.wilts.sch.uk</center></p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And Css file:

```
....
  .science {
      padding-top: 30px;
  }

  .center-block{
      text-align: center;
  }
  .center-block .alco {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      text-align: center;
      padding-right:150px;
  }
  .center-block .nersys{
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        padding-left:150px;
  }

  .alcoimage {
      padding-top: 60px;
  }

  #footer {
      background:#40ea3c;
      width:100%;
      height:80px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    color: white;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot.